# Combine Where statement with same attribute

Tags: php, sql

I want to create web page which user will select "previous date" until certain date including their shift(day or night).below are the example.

[image]

here i also provide my table P_tracking and my sql
[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM P_Tracking
WHERE (ProductionDate >='2014-04-14'
       AND ProductionShift='N')
  AND (ProductionDate <= '2014-04-25'
       AND ProductionShift = 'D')
```

my sql query seem didnt work. Can anyone help me solve this. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
select * from P_Tracking where
   ProductionDate between '2014-04-14' and '2014-04-25'
 AND
  ProductionShift in ('D','N')
```

because you both conditions can't be true at the same time, so you will get no results, so you have to use `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: if "OR" the output that I want not correct because it will showed up all dates from before 25 april. But I want the output start from 14-4-2014 until 25-4-2014.